# Filter child select box value from parent using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two selection boxes,one contains country names and another contains all state names of all countries.

```
<select id="parent">
 <option value="Country1">Country1</option>
 <option value="Country2">Country2</option>
 <option value="Country3">Country3</option>
</select>

<select id="child">
 <option value="Country1 state1">Country1 state1</option>
 <option value="Country1 state2">Country1 state2</option>
 <option value="Country2 state1">Country2 state1</option>
 <option value="Country2 state2">Country2 state2</option>
 <option value="Country3 state1">Country3 state1</option>
</select>
```

Then if i select country1 from parent selection box, the state selection box has need to show all states of country1 alone and remove all other states from it.

I need to find the child values by partial match and verify with the parent value..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#parent').change(function(){
  var filter = $(this).val();
  $('option').each(function(){
   if ($('option:contains("' + var1 '")') == filter) {     
    $(this).show();
   } else {
    $(this).hide();
   }
  var var1= $('#child').val(filter);
  })
 })
})
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Check the source of Chained Selects jQuery plugin. It does something very similar using class names. You should be able to adapt from there. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent").change(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    $("#a").append('a');
    $('select#child option').each(function(){
       $("#a").append('a');
       if ( $(this).val().substring(0,8) == filter) {     
          $(this).show();
       } 
       else {
           $(this).hide();
       }
    });

   var var1= $('#child').val(filter);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yZm7A/3/

although as one sees there remains the problem of the selected value in the second dropdown not changing

Comment: mind that `$(this).val()` is never `==filter` but rather starts with `filter`. So one should check if `$(this).val().substring(0, 8) == filter`

Answer (score 0):

Try IE

```
else {
   $(this).hide();
}
```

change it to

```
else {
   $(this).remove();
}
```